# ngrok forwarding link never loads

Tags: python, twilio, ngrok

I'm building a bot with Twilio to send and receive SMS's from my script to my phone, etc. In order to parse the message response sent from my phone, I needed to set up a small Flask app, host it on a public url with ngrok, then attach the ngrok forwarding url to Twilio as my webhook link.

For whatever reason, when I started my ngrok server, and see this screen in terminal [image]

and then paste the forwarding link into my URL bar, I either receive a `Deceptive Site Warning` in Chrome, or it just never loads. Any thoughts what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you able to load your application at localhost:5000?

Comment: @philnash yes. My route is "/sms", so loading `localhost:5000/sms` loads the page.

Comment: In your screenshot you are loading just the root path `/`. What happens when you try to load `subdomain.ngrok.io/sms`?